# Google Cloud Run: Out of memory (Bug?)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

Heyho!

I'm trying to deploy a machine learning model on Google Cloud Run. On my machine it needs around 2,5 GB, but when I try to run it via GCR I always get an out or memory error even though I put a 4 GB limit.
I also tried it in a to 4 GB limited Virtual Machine and everything works perfectly.

Is there a big overhead I don't know about or is it a bug?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question has no details regarding the problem. We have no idea what you have done or how to reproduce it. Read this link and improve your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you share the error that you have in the logs?

Comment: The error is "out of memory error: process used 41xx MB from 40xx MB"

Comment: and concurrency is set to 1 by the way

Comment: How do you get the 2.5Gb metrics on your local machine?

Comment: sorry for the late answers all the time... i just `top` and looked at RES. and as i said i also tried it in a qemu vm limited to 4 gigs with -m 4000M.

Comment: i even tried it on a physical device with 4 gigs now. everything working perfectly. @guillaumeblaquiere

Comment: 4GB is really new. Open a case [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues) (if you haven't a paid support)

Comment: Can you give us some sense of what you're doing in the application? Are instances long lived, or are there lots of cold starts?

Comment: Processing takes 15 - 20 seconds. As concurrency is set to 1 there would be a lot of cold starts probably if I make it publicly accessible.

Comment: Hello, I am from Google Cloud Platform Support, please open a [Support case](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/role-based-support) for this issue and if you don't have a support package then please open an issue in [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) in order to inspect your project as it seems a bug to you.